# Iterate through array and sum if conditions met

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having trouble figuring out how to map out a solution for this problem... and ideas?

Check to see if the age on each person is an array. If it is, sum up each number value and update age to be this value. Then, make a list of people that are only over the age of 25 based on this updated number.

```
const ListOfPeople = [
{
  name: 'Mia',
  age: [10, 5, 5]
},
{
  name: 'Steve',
  age: 30
},
{
  name: 'Emma',
  age: [2, 12, 16, 10]
}
];
```

I started with this:

```
let filterPeople = ListOfPeople => ListOfPeople.map(person =>
person[0].age //stuck
);
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yourself yet, or are you just asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: `[].concat(age)` evaluates to an array given an value or an array eg `[].concat(30) -> [30]` and `[].concat([1,2,3]) -> [1,2,3]`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not asking for the solution to the problem, but suggestions on how to approach it or methods to research. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Break down each of these steps into its own function. Which one are you unable to implement?

Comment: @generalhenry: Are you trying to cast Steve's age to become an array type? But my understanding from the question is to skip Steve since the age is not an array type, so ultimately only return Emma and Mia

Comment: Thanks @4castle. I think I know how to solve the last couple steps (adding up the ages and creating a new list) but I'm unsure as to how to loop through and access the value of the age key to start with

Comment: @IsaacLem I'm suggesting a way of casting age into an array that's more one liner friendly than an if statement or a ternary. So that you can then address the summation of the age array.

Comment: You can access the age property using `person.age`.

Comment: @4castle I'm getting an error saying that person.age isn't a function: const over25Folks = ListOfPeople.map(person => {
  person.age.filter(person => person.length >= 25)
});
console.log(over25Folks);

Comment: Use `const over25Folks = ListOfPeople.filter(person => person.age >= 25);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const over30 = ListOfPeople.map(p => {
    if (Array.isArray(p.age)) {
        // Copy the object so we don't mutate the original
        p = Object.assign({}, p);
        p.age = p.age.reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0);
    }
    return p;
}).filter(p => p.age >= 30);
console.log(over30);
```